# XSLT replace with dynamic content

Tags: xslt, replace

I have a String (inside a variable) in XSLT. Within this string I need to replace any `\E\.br\E\` with `\.br\`. This was quite simple to do with a XSLT 2.0 replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($myString,'[\\]E[\\].br[\\]E[\\]','\\.br\\')"/>
```

But I need to replace any occurence starting `\E\.` and ending again with `\E\`. This would mean: `\E\.anything\E\` to be replaced to `\.anything\`.

But I would have to store the `anything`that is between the `\E\`.

**Is there an advanced replace function that can keep the intermediate information** - or do I need to loop over the string and search manually for each occurence? If yes - how do I loop within a string variable in XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group subexpressions in your pattern e.g. `replace($myString, '([\\]E)([\\].*?[\\])(E[\\])', '$2')` and the reference a group with `$index` in the replacement string.

Comment: This works. Thanks. My code now is: `<xsl:value-of select="replace($replacedContent,'([\\]E[\\][.])([a-z]{2})([\\]E[\\])','\\.$2\\')"/>`